# Compiling servlets for tomcat

Tags: java, servlets, javac

Hello
I am trying to modify one of the default files that comes with tomcat *SessionExample.java*, and trying to compile it but I get an error.

```
javac -classpath "E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.18\lib\servlet-api.jar" SessionExample.java
```

Gives me this error

```
SessionExample.java:26: package util does not exist
import util.HTMLFilter;
           ^
SessionExample.java:90: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable HTMLFilter
location: class SessionExample
            out.println(HTMLFilter.filter(name) + " = "
                        ^
SessionExample.java:91: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable HTMLFilter
location: class SessionExample
                        + HTMLFilter.filter(value) + "
");
                          ^
3 errors
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compile `HTMLFilter`. Use can use the `-sourcepath` switch. See the [javac docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html). Consider using some IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans

Comment: I added this and it works now -sourcepath "E:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.18\webapps\examples\WEB-INF\classes". Thank you.